How to stop axios from printing the GET request automatically?
I am trying to access the html of a product page through its link specifically using axios. When i make the request for this product the program decides to print the entire response on its own, even when there's no console.log() statements.
import axios from 'axios';

const link = "https://www.flipkart.com/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201"

async function getFlipkartProduct(productLink) {

    const response = await axios.get(productLink);
    console.log("ok");
    return null;

}

await getFlipkartProduct(link);

Here's the output that prints in the console on its own:
 [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
        [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: null,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(verified)]: true,
        [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: null,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: <ref *2> Timeout {
          _idleTimeout: 5000,
          _idlePrev: TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular *2],
            _idlePrev: [Circular *2],
            expiry: 5232,
            id: -9007199254740991,
            msecs: 5000,
            priorityQueuePosition: 1
          },
          _idleNext: TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular *2],
            _idlePrev: [Circular *2],
            expiry: 5232,
            id: -9007199254740991,
            msecs: 5000,
            priorityQueuePosition: 1
          },
          _idleStart: 475,
          _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
          _timerArgs: undefined,
          _repeat: null,
          _destroyed: false,
          [Symbol(refed)]: false,
          [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
          [Symbol(asyncId)]: 309,
          [Symbol(triggerId)]: 307
        },
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-S
HA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA2
56:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
          checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
          minDHSize: 1024,
          maxRedirects: 21,
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          protocol: 'https:',
          path: null,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: [Object: null prototype] {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
          },
          agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
          auth: undefined,
          family: undefined,
          beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
          beforeRedirects: { proxy: [Function: beforeRedirect] },
          hostname: 'www.flipkart.com',
          port: 443,
          agent: undefined,
          nativeProtocols: { 'http:': [Object], 'https:': [Object] },
          pathname: '/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj',
          search: '?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202u
dU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201',
          _defaultAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object: null prototype],
            requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
            sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
            freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: true,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'lifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 1,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          host: 'www.flipkart.com',
          keepAlive: true,
          scheduling: 'lifo',
          timeout: 5000,
          noDelay: true,
          servername: 'www.flipkart.com',
          _agentKey: 'www.flipkart.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
          encoding: null,
          keepAliveInitialDelay: 1000
        }
      },
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *3],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      responseUrl: 'https://www.flipkart.com/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2
Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077
201',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'x-captcha-validate',
        'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-captcha-validate',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://www.flipkart.com',
        'x-captcha-validate': 'true',
        'content-length': '783',
        'content-type': 'text/html'
      },
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 14,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'www.flipkart.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _events: {
        close: undefined,
        error: [Function: handleRequestError],
        prefinish: undefined,
        finish: undefined,
        drain: undefined,
        response: [Function: handleResponse],
        socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
      },
      _writableState: WritableState {
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        length: 0,
        corked: 0,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedIndex: 0,
        pendingcb: 0,
        [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
        [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
      },
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: {
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        protocol: 'https:',
        path: '/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&o
tracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: [Object: null prototype] {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
        },
        agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
        auth: undefined,
        family: undefined,
        beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
        beforeRedirects: { proxy: [Function: beforeRedirect] },
        hostname: 'www.flipkart.com',
        port: '',
        agent: undefined,
        nativeProtocols: {
          'http:': {
            _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
            METHODS: [Array],
            STATUS_CODES: [Object],
            Agent: [Function],
            ClientRequest: [Function: ClientRequest],
            IncomingMessage: [Function: IncomingMessage],
            OutgoingMessage: [Function: OutgoingMessage],
            Server: [Function: Server],
            ServerResponse: [Function: ServerResponse],
            createServer: [Function: createServer],
            validateHeaderName: [Function],
            validateHeaderValue: [Function],
            get: [Function: get],
            request: [Function: request],
            setMaxIdleHTTPParsers: [Function: setMaxIdleHTTPParsers],
            maxHeaderSize: [Getter],
            globalAgent: [Getter/Setter]
          },
          'https:': {
            Agent: [Function: Agent],
            globalAgent: [Agent],
            Server: [Function: Server],
            createServer: [Function: createServer],
            get: [Function: get],
            request: [Function: request]
          }
        },
        pathname: '/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj',
        search: '?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU
4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201'
      },
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *3],
      _currentUrl: 'https://www.flipkart.com/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2
Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077
201',
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
      'user-agent': [ 'User-Agent', 'axios/1.7.9' ],
      'accept-encoding': [ 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, compress, deflate, br' ],
      host: [ 'Host', 'www.flipkart.com' ]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'x-captcha-validate',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'x-captcha-validate',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://www.flipkart.com',
      'x-captcha-validate': 'true',
      'content-length': '783',
      'content-type': 'text/html'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: {
        silentJSONParsing: true,
        forcedJSONParsing: true,
        clarifyTimeoutError: false
      },
      adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
      transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
      transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: {
        FormData: [Function: FormData] {
          LINE_BREAK: '\r\n',
          DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/octet-stream'
        },
        Blob: [class Blob]
      },
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': undefined,
        'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
      },
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://www.flipkart.com/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fi
v8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201',   
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *3> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        abort: [Function (anonymous)],
        aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
        connect: [Function (anonymous)],
        error: [Function (anonymous)],
        socket: [Function (anonymous)],
        timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
        finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
      },
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: <ref *1> TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: {
          allowHalfOpen: undefined,
          pipe: false,
          secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          isServer: false,
          requestCert: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          session: undefined,
          ALPNProtocols: undefined,
          requestOCSP: undefined,
          enableTrace: undefined,
          pskCallback: undefined,
          highWaterMark: undefined,
          onread: undefined,
          signal: undefined
        },
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        secureConnecting: false,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'www.flipkart.com',
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          close: [
            [Function: onSocketCloseDestroySSL],
            [Function],
            [Function: onClose]
          ],
          end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
          error: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
            listener: [Function: freeSocketErrorListener]
          },
          newListener: [Function: keylogNewListener],
          connect: undefined,
          secure: [Function: onConnectSecure],
          session: [Function (anonymous)],
          free: [Function: onFree],
          timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
          agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
          data: undefined,
          drain: undefined
        },
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.flipkart.com',
        _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: [],
          bufferIndex: 0,
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          [Symbol(kState)]: 60303620
        },
        _writableState: WritableState {
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          length: 0,
          corked: 0,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writelen: 0,
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          pendingcb: 0,
          [Symbol(kState)]: 17563908,
          [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null,
          [Symbol(kWriteCbValue)]: null
        },
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: null,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
        [Symbol(res)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: null,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(verified)]: true,
        [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: -1,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: TLSWrap {
          _parent: TCP {
            reading: [Getter/Setter],
            onconnection: null,
            [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
          },
          _parentWrap: null,
          _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {} },
          reading: true,
          onkeylog: [Function: onkeylog],
          onhandshakestart: [Function: noop],
          onhandshakedone: [Function (anonymous)],
          onocspresponse: [Function: onocspresponse],
          onnewsession: [Function: onnewsessionclient],
          onerror: [Function: onerror],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: <ref *2> Timeout {
          _idleTimeout: 5000,
          _idlePrev: TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular *2],
            _idlePrev: [Circular *2],
            expiry: 5232,
            id: -9007199254740991,
            msecs: 5000,
            priorityQueuePosition: 1
          },
          _idleNext: TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular *2],
            _idlePrev: [Circular *2],
            expiry: 5232,
            id: -9007199254740991,
            msecs: 5000,
            priorityQueuePosition: 1
          },
          _idleStart: 475,
          _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
          _timerArgs: undefined,
          _repeat: null,
          _destroyed: false,
          [Symbol(refed)]: false,
          [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
          [Symbol(asyncId)]: 309,
          [Symbol(triggerId)]: 307
        },
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 1,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(connect-options)]: {
          rejectUnauthorized: true,
          ciphers: 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-S
HA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA2
56:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA',
          checkServerIdentity: [Function: checkServerIdentity],
          minDHSize: 1024,
          maxRedirects: 21,
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          protocol: 'https:',
          path: null,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: [Object: null prototype] {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.9',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
          },
          agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
          auth: undefined,
          family: undefined,
          beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
          beforeRedirects: { proxy: [Function: beforeRedirect] },
          hostname: 'www.flipkart.com',
          port: 443,
          agent: undefined,
          nativeProtocols: { 'http:': [Object], 'https:': [Object] },
          pathname: '/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj',
          search: '?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202u
dU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201',
          _defaultAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object: null prototype],
            requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
            sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
            freeSockets: [Object: null prototype],
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: true,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'lifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 1,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          host: 'www.flipkart.com',
          keepAlive: true,
          scheduling: 'lifo',
          timeout: 5000,
          noDelay: true,
          servername: 'www.flipkart.com',
          _agentKey: 'www.flipkart.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::',
          encoding: null,
          keepAliveInitialDelay: 1000
        }
      },
      _header: 'GET /vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_
1_2&otracker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +     
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.7.9\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: www.flipkart.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: Agent {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          free: [Function (anonymous)],
          newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object: null prototype] {
          keepAlive: true,
          scheduling: 'lifo',
          timeout: 5000,
          noDelay: true,
          path: null
        },
        requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
        sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
        freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {
          'www.flipkart.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [ [TLSSocket] ]
        },
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        scheduling: 'lifo',
        maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
        totalSocketCount: 1,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: {
          map: {
            'www.flipkart.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Buffer [Uint8Array]]
          },
          list: [ 'www.flipkart.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::' ]
        },
        [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/vega-cliff-motorbike-helmet/p/itmfcz57cwhqvvfj?pid=HLMEEWKHENEQREMN&lid=LSTHLMEEWKHENEQREMNUIPXY0&marketplace=FLIPKART&store=1mt%2Fztf%2Fiv8%2Ftih&srno=b_1_2&otr
acker=browse&iid=en_mC2lsKHtuWwa0ISQB202udU4Ag_hDkEx8N_o-HI_sUmTiCT6UqHVQXfXTBNd435VMQRjzXCBpgLy-ls26rN5nQ%3D%3D&ssid=dpx48ydrsw0000001733820077201',
      _ended: true,


 ... some more characters that do not fit in the question...


      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
        'user-agent': [ 'User-Agent', 'axios/1.7.9' ],
        'accept-encoding': [ 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, compress, deflate, br' ],
        host: [ 'Host', 'www.flipkart.com' ]
      },
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><meta charset=UTF-8><meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"name=viewport><title>Flipkart reCAPTCHA</title><link href=https:/
/static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/s/recaptcha.css rel=stylesheet><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Lc49B0pAAAAAIVgOhfwW8
i7t7SRO0KSnlSVZRAq"></script><script src=https://static-assets-web.flixcart.com/batman-returns/batman-returns/s/recaptcha.js async defer></script><div class=container><img alt
="Flipkart Logo"class=logo src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/60/60/promos/14/06/2024/88011666-ce1d-40f0-a8eb-1bac7d164885.png?q=60"><h1 class=header>Are you a human?</h1
><p class=subText>Confirming...<div class=loaderContainer><div class=loader></div></div></div>'
  },
  status: 403
}

Node.js v20.18.0

The problem does not occur for other links like amazon product links. How do i prevent it from automatically printing the entire response?

Please show an example of what exactly gets printed where.

@deceze Updated question with the output

Not sure what causes axios to log this to console (default configuration for 403 response?) - but what you got at the very end there appears to be a response document that contains <title>Flipkart reCAPTCHA</title> and <h1 class=header>Are you a human?</h1>, pretty strongly indicating that you are running into an anti-bot mechanism ...

Can you replace Axios with fetch?
